# Robot- Selenium : How we can handle a element (text box) whose ID is changing dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am facing one simple problem-- there is one Add button in the web page, After clicking that a small pop up window (Not in another browser tab , without title) opened having 3 text box.  These id/xpath is getting changed whenever will click on Add button. I need to to enter few data and then save.

Could you please help me how we can handle this dynamic  xpath/id ---text box in robot selenium framework. Is there any way we can input on text box based on label. Please share any pointer or sample code.

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML of the elements and which Text-box you are looking after to interact?

Comment: Hi Kunduk, not able to take screen shots. But find solution now.

Comment: was using xpath as 
//*[@id="widget.cbid.network.neweb6e3a.target"] where in between value was changing dynamically. Was able to solve with contains (@id, 'traget')